# How to debug a problem with GET Express Router

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I develop a game with a MEAN stack, so I need to create the API with Node & MongoDB to store scores and using this API in a Angular client.

The database is OK and I can add a score with POST but now I try to query the database with the API and the GET method not working.

I try to create a simple response (route /) but the response is the Angular client (index.html) in Postman, the POST work but the GET not !

```
classRouter.post('/add', (req, res) => {
  // Check request body
  if (typeof req.body === 'undefined' || req.body === null) {
    sendBodyError(res, Vocabulary.errors.noBody)
  };
  // Check fields in the body
  const {
    miss,
    extra,
    ok
  } = checkFields(Mandatory.game, req.body);

  //=> Error: bad fields provided
  if (!ok) {
    sendFieldsError(res, Vocabulary.errors.badFields, miss, extra)
  }
  else {
    //=> Request is valid: use controller
    createScore(req.body)
      .then(apiResponse => sendApiSuccessResponse(res, Vocabulary.request.success, apiResponse))
      .catch(apiResponse => sendApiErrorResponse(res, Vocabulary.request.error, apiResponse))
  };
});

// Route for all score
classRouter.get('/all', (req, res) => {
  getAllScores()
    .then(apiResponse => sendApiSuccessResponse(res, Vocabulary.request.success, apiResponse))
    .catch(apiResponse => sendApiErrorResponse(res, Vocabulary.request.error, apiResponse))
});

classRouter.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('GET request to the homepage');
});
```

```
const createScore = body => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Register new user
    ScoreModel.create(body)
      .then(mongoResponse => resolve(mongoResponse))
      .catch(mongoResponse => reject(mongoResponse))
  });
};

// Get all scores from the database
const getAllScores = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ScoreModel.find((error, item) => {
      // Request error
      if (error) {
        return reject(error)
      } else {
        return resolve(item)
      };
    });
  });
};
```

If someone can help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) package for debugging purposes.

First of all you need to log `apiResponse` within `then()` to make sure that the function `getAllScores` returns what you really expected.

But it appears, however, your problem doesn't related to these things.
You need to put a `return` before function `getAllScores`.

```
classRouter.get( '/all', (req, res) => {
    return getAllScores()
        .then( apiResponse => sendApiSuccessResponse(res, Vocabulary.request.success, apiResponse) )
        .catch( apiResponse => sendApiErrorResponse(res, Vocabulary.request.error, apiResponse))
});
```

Comment: I try but it doesn't work, I don't think the error is in the function because classRouter.get('/', function (req, res) {
                res.send('GET request to the homepage');
            }); not work

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I like to use some kind of IDE to provide it to me. I use WebStorm